# Painting convex area of an object

Tags: matlab, image-processing

[image]

Hi,
I have an image is above. I calculate convex area of the object but also I want to paint the area that is between convex area and real object area with any colour.

Is it possible to do this painting operation?

Comment: Put some code in the line and show what you have achieved already. No offence, but to me, this looks like a drawing in Paint.

Comment: @NKN No, it is not a drawing in paint. I have a lot of object like this in my mask. I just zoomed this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `regionprops` and `'ConvexImage'` property

```
bw = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2BiO.jpg');
bw = bw(:,:,1)>128; %// read your image and convert to binary
s = regionprops(bw,'ConvexImage','BoundingBox'); %// get ConvexImage property
n = uint8(bw); %// new output image
n( floor( s.BoundingBox(2) ) + (1:s.BoundingBox(4) ),...
   floor( s.BoundingBox(1) ) + (1:s.BoundingBox(2) ) = ...
   n( floor( s.BoundingBox(2) ) + (1:s.BoundingBox(4) ),...
      floor( s.BoundingBox(1) ) + (1:s.BoundingBox(2) ) + ...
   uint8( s.ConvexImage ); %// add convex image to original
figure; imshow( n ); colormap( rand(3) ); %// show result with random colormap
```

Note how `'BoundingBox'` information is used to locate `'ConvexImage'` inside the input image `n` and `bw`.

Your result should look like:
[image]